# SpringBoot: How to pass data from one controller to another?

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I am creating a JSP page where I would want to display a table with data from an ArrayList. I have 2 controllers and I would like to pass the ArrayList data from PageController.java to Controller.java

This is my PageController.java

```
package org.monitor;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PageController {
    static Properties prop = new Properties();
    public static ArrayList<String> runtimeCommand = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> runtime = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    static {
        loadProperty();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        new PageController().mainProgram();
    }
    
    public void mainProgram() throws IOException{
        
        for(int i=0; i < runtimeCommand.size(); i++) {
            String output = runCMD(runtimeCommand.get(i));
            runtime.add(output);
            System.out.println(runtime.get(i));
        }
    }
    
    public String runCMD(String commandline) throws IOException {
        String command = commandline;
        Process p;
        if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("windows") != -1) {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C " + command); 
        }
        else {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        }
        
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String output;
        
        while((output = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            return output;
        }
        return output;
    }
    
    public static void loadProperty() {
        
        String localDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        try(InputStream input = new FileInputStream(localDir + "/src/main/resources/properties/page.properties")) { 
            
            prop.load(input);
            runtimeCommand.addAll(Arrays.asList(prop.getProperty("runtime.cmd").split(",")));
            
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Controller.java

```
package org.boot;

import java.util.*;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.monitor.*;

@RestController
public class Controller {
        
        @GetMapping("/web")
        public String index() {
            
            //http://localhost:port/web
            return "Greetings from Spring Boot Quartz!";
        }
        
        @RequestMapping("/web/page")    
         public ModelAndView page() {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("page");
            PageController page = new PageController();
            ArrayList<String> runtimeList = new ArrayList<String>();
            runtimeList = page.runtime;
            model.addObject("runtime", runtimeList.get(0));     
            return model;           
        }
```

I used ${runtime} to display on my JSP.

The error I got was: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
so meaning runtimeList in Controller.java is empty. How do I pass data from one controller to another successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are simply calling

```
PageController page = new PageController();
```

Inside the /web/page request, you always create a new PageController which has not been initialized jet.

This will result in an empty runtime list.

Without exactly knowing the call order, I can only guess a solution.

- Never use "new" in a SpringBoot application. It's all about dependency injection. Let Spring create the Beans.
- Annotate the Page controller with @Component . Make it an Initializing bean by adding "implements InitializingBean" and implement the "afterPropertiesSet" method which loads your data (move the code from main program to afterpropertyset).
- Add @Autowired PageController pagecontroller = null; in your controller. And then use pagecontroller.runtime to get the data. (For better control, make a getter for runtime)

Spring will now create the PageController and load the data. Then it will inject the PageController into your controller, and you can simply use it.